# Pygame No module named pygame error in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have installed Python 3.5.2 (32-bit) and Python 3.3 pygame -1.9.2a0 on Windows 10. When I run IDLE (python shell) and try to import pygame i get 'No module named pygame' error. I have found sys.path in the shell but pygame is not there. How can I set the variable for pygame OR how I can resolve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Installed pygame "pygame-1.9.3-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl" using 'pip' resolved this. Pip installer comes with python 3 and runs with windows command prompt(not in python shell).

Answer (score -1):

You can try **re-installing pygame**!
Go to the terminal**(command prompt)** on windows!
Do *Win+R* and type *cmd*.
Once in cmd, type: **pip install pygame**

If it doesn't work still, try and check out the **pygame FAQ site**!

It is: *https://www.pygame.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions*

Comment: If you use Pycharm, then there is a built in terminal!